# Should questions include System/Setting in title if tagged with system/setting?

Tags: discussion, faq, tags, questions, game-systems

For example: "WFRP2e--Does Tzenntch bully Nurgle, if so, can he be reported, and to who?"

Then tag the question with *WFRP* and *religion-and-deities*. My thought is that the question lead should be dropped. The tag(s) are the filter and context, provided the question framing is appropriately worded.

---

[Return to FAQ Index](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7064/23970)

Comment: Related: [When does it make sense for a question title to specify the edition?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7267/33569)

Comment: Relevant MSE post: [How do I write a good title?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/10647/335251)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In general, the system probably shouldn't go in the title.

The system should be tagged. SE appends high-use tags to question titles in several situations (notably Google results). This means that if you both tag the system AND include it in the title, you'll get something like "WFRP -- WFRPT2e--Does Tzenntch..." Yuck.

This also leads to cleaner, more enticing question titles. Which helps draw people in who may know enough to answer your question, but don't meet the exact system (i.e. lore nuts, or people who can answer questions that aren't strictly RAW).

For many RPG systems, I would say that it's also a good idea to mention system/edition information in the body of the question. System is a nice detail to have somewhere that's a bit more durable than tags. For RPGs that don't have a large question volume yet and are at risk of tag-reaping, including the system in the body is essential.

This isn't a hard-and-fast rule, though. There are cases where disambiguating the system in the question title can be useful (particularly if a term in your question has meanings in several popular systems).

Comment: i was considering editing a question that added **Forgotten Realms--** to the question, and wanted clarity before doing so. Thanks!

Comment: The problem in [that particular question](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/12662/how-much-information-is-there-about-the-wall-of-the-faithless-and-the-crusades-a) was that the appended tag was only marginally related to the question. Thankfully it could be resolved by re-tagging it to something else (i.e., instead of "dnd-3.5e" i used "pre-spellplague"), but couldn't there be another similar case where the solution is not that simple?

Comment: @yandros Personally, I don't think that we need to go out of our way to get Forgotten Realms into the title... The "Wall of the Faithless" is a fairly unambiguous term. Work Forgotten Realms into the body, and you should be fine. Also keep in mind that "pre-spellplague" is an extremely narrow tag, and likely to go away over time.

Comment: Google's changed how titles are shown. The tag that SE adds automatically is usually stripped out now, making it hard to know what game a result is about at a glance. See this [example search](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7wcRX.png) showing only one result with an added tag.