# When discussing the “don’t guess the system” policy, let’s make a special effort to assume everyone is acting in good faith

Tags: discussion, etiquette

Community discussions about our [“don’t guess the system” policy](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11280/62294) happen from time to time, and it has been my observation that these discussions can often get...what’s a good word for it...*intense*? I have often seen these discussions either begin as, or devolve into, adversarial confrontations - of this I am no less guilty than anyone.

I’m not asking anyone to dial down the intensity - we’re all passionate about rpg.se. But as you approach these discussions with fervor, let’s try our best to begin with one foundational assumption:

*Everyone wants what is best for the site and is acting in good faith to see that realized.*

Let’s approach this issue (and all issues, really) from the assumption that everyone engaged is acting in good faith. No one has some secret, nefarious agenda to push, and no one wants to make the stack worse.

Just be nice and remember there’s a person behind the avatar that wants the stack to be the best it can be, just as you do.

We’re building this together.

Comment: It's just so said that Assuming Good Faith is not present in the current code of conduct, while good faith is required: "*Those who don’t follow the Code of Conduct in good faith may face repercussions deemed appropriate by our moderation team*"

Comment: @Baskakov People very much want it [back in the CoC](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/335026) and I've at least seen RPG.SE completely ignore the fact that it was silently excluded from there. I have seen the people here teating the site as if it were still a rule, and I do believe they do this simply because it is kind and helpful to do so

Comment: Yep - just like Parliament/Congress