# Is it possible to search for edits with a certain content, specifically adding a tag?

Tags: support, tags, editing, search

[In the spirit of good faith](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11569/when-discussing-the-don-t-guess-the-system-policy-let-s-make-a-special-effort), here are my fears and weaknesses.

People mistake system-specific questions for rarely-encountered systems as either [system-agnostic](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/system-agnostic) or [dnd-5e](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dnd-5e) questions about once every couple months. (Here's [a question about putting armor on in combat](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/172271/is-there-a-cost-for-donning-or-doffing-a-shield-and-armor-during-combat). Here's [a question about mitigating critical hits](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/161718/is-there-any-way-to-mitigate-crits). Here's [a question about a paladin using Lay on Hands on himself](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/72484/can-a-paladin-use-lay-on-hands-on-himself). You'll need enough rep to view deleted answers, though.) While that doesn't sound like a big issue, those systems might only be asked about once a month.

Consensus is currently that we're allowing experts to be experts and add system tags they think are appropriate, rather than closing the question as unclear and waiting for the original asker to edit the tags. But even experts make mistakes. Somebody who mistakes a system is likely to mistake that it deserves a system tag. Especially in the case of [dnd-5e](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dnd-5e), that tag is going to take it off my radar more or less entirely.

It's not very likely that a suggested edit like that is going to make it out of queue, but 2,000-rep users have been mistaken in the past and they don't need to go through queue.

I don't want to look through every [dnd-5e](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dnd-5e) question on the off-chance somebody edited it to add an inappropriate tag. Not only is it time-consuming but it's so unlikely compared to the total volume of questions that I'll probably be suffering from alarm fatigue and skip right over it when I check.

So: **is it possible to search recent edits for a specific operation, in this case adding [system-agnostic](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/system-agnostic) or [dnd-5e](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dnd-5e)?**

---

(Just to pull it out of volatile comments, here's [the final SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/rpg/revision/1419926/1745410/tag-edits-which-edit-in-a-certain-tag) from earlier discussion, which shows the last date a tag was edited onto a question.)

Comment: Do you have some examples of posts where this has happened? I'd be curious to see what questions are getting this treatment.

Comment: @LCooper I'm not aware of any posts where another user has mistakenly added the dnd-5e tag, because we've tried to close systemless questions as unclear though that is changing.

Comment: So this is a purely hypothetical question, then? Most of the examples I've seen where people are advocating for adding the dnd-5e tag have been for posts referencing, say, Van Richten's Guide to Ravenloft, and even *that* type of edit is treated as a little controversial. If this is a problem that's been happening previously, then that's a different kettle of fish entirely.

Comment: @LCooper No, I'm just not aware of any posts where this has happened, because as stated I haven't examined literally every question tagged dnd-5e to see if any of them are mistagged. Assuming an asker isn't going to mistag their own system, looking through the history of a particular type of edit activity seems like a good way to become more aware.

Comment: I’d say it’s pretty unlikely based on my activity alone, not to mention how many other active community curators we have doing great work. There isn’t much that I miss, and what I do miss is always handled appropriately.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### SEDE to the rescue

This is outside what you can do with directly site tools, however we have SEDE for those who know the secret tongue of databases. While my skills are limited, I did modify something similar into what [I think you want](https://data.stackexchange.com/rpg/revision/1419879/1745359/tag-edits-which-edit-in-a-certain-tag).

Of note, it'll return all questions which have been edited to add the specified tag. It'll list them by ID, with higher ID being more recent questions. Most of these are going to be legitimate: edits by the querent, someone fixing their tag based on info in the post or comment, etc. It also doesn't include deleted questions, which is gonna include some number of cases where the tag was edited in, rolled back, and ultimately never clarified.

Comment: Cool. It shows the tags for the question as they are now rather than in the edit that happened; I thought the query was grabbing bad results because the first one is actually someone erroneously tagging [a D&D question from before dnd-5e](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/8721/what-is-the-point-of-a-spell-component-pouch) as dnd-5e.

Comment: @Glazius We actually have 5e questions going back to 2012 because a lot of D&D Next questions are now [dnd-5e]. I did [a version](https://data.stackexchange.com/rpg/revision/1419879/1745395/tag-edits-which-edit-in-a-certain-tag) which pulls out edit date and tags, if you're interested

Comment: Ah, cool. I'm a bit of a whisperer myself, here's [a version](https://data.stackexchange.com/rpg/revision/1419926/1745410/tag-edits-which-edit-in-a-certain-tag) which sorts by edit time and only shows the latest edit.

Comment: @Glazius You get one token of affection for that one (unfortunately, it is only of sentimental value.)